# Can't detect I2C displays with Arduino Nano

Tags: i2c

All cables tested and work:

```
SCL - A5
SDA - A4
VCC - 5V
GND - GND
```

I'm using an Arduino Nano board and an I<sup>2</sup>C display - I've tried everything to get it to work and I'm now convinced it's a hardware fault. Using the Arduino I<sup>2</sup>C address scanner, it is unable to find a device, even though it is wired correctly (I've checked multiple times).

[image: Nano and I2C display]

This is the code I used, [i2c_scanner](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner), and this output:

```
Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Scanning...
No I2C devices found
```

... is all I get.

Any suggestions, or is my board output fried?

Comment: To use i2c you normally need pullup resistors on sda and scl, except if the slave device has some. Add 2 pullup resistors to your circuit (you can use 10k, that should be ok).

Comment: You need to understand how I2C works first.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava what has he misunderstood?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have two issues here:

- As already pointed out, you have the white wire connected to the wrong pin on the Arduino
- Also, **you need to solder the headers on the Arduino.** There is no solder on the pins, which means that there is no connection. You need to solder those headers on; it looks like you just set the Arduino on top, which won't work with headers

Comment: Agreed absolutely. Shoving the header pins into the holes simply won't work. You **must** solder them.

Answer (score 2):

Check the solder jumper on the display. Note the example code is for one address, but two addresses are supported. Try the other address in code, or solder the LCD address pads to select the address to match the code. I had the same problem, the printed address on the LCD solder pads is just the last address bits that make the difference.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, with a lot of time lost, I tried to give current from another source, (an Arduino one) is all works, I think these Nano clones have some bugs on output voltages, to be checked. Anyway, so it worked.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an answer, or a comment.

Comment: @Greenonline You could flag it as "not an answer", but it will probably be declined and you'll be told the reason is - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer. In my opinion, if a person is going to answer a 3 year old question that the OP has abandoned, it better be a good answer. This answer does not address any of the issues that are clearly visible in the OP's picture, not does it point out the incorrect wiring. You could try flagging it as "very low quality" and see what happens.

Comment: @VE7JRO - Good point, I had flagged it as "Not an answer" but I have retracted it, for the reasons you state, although it would serve better as a comment. I'll leave it be, even though the obvious answer is that of Anonymous Penguin, as I don't want to earn any more declined flags :-). Also, I am not sure why there are *two* answers from the *same* user.